# Short story about a robot who outlives his humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, robots

Trying to remember the title of a short story about a robot who survives several generations of a family, and at one point stows away on a spaceship. It was an older story — I want to say pre-1970 — part of an anthology. There was some reason why he stowed away. Maybe he was trying to get home? His longevity figured into the plot somehow. He might have been facing obsolescence.

Comment: How old is an older story? You've got a start on the details, but can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if it can help you [edit] in any more details?

Comment: I want to say pre-1970. There was some reason why he stowed away. he was trying to get home? His longevity figured into the plot somehow. he might have been facing obsolescence?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's "All the Traps of Earth" by Clifford Simak.  It was first printed in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction, March 1960.  See https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41672 for more.

The robot is named Richard Daniel. It served the Barrington family for six hundred years and when the story starts, the family is extinct and the estate -- robot included -- is being sold. The robot stows away on the outside of an interstellar ship and gains psi powers from the experience. He settles on a frontier planet and uses his powers to help people.

Comment: My pleasure -- it was always a favorite story for me.

Comment: A long-lived robot named R. Daniel, who has psi powers? Gee, what a curious, ehm, what's the tactful word.

Comment: I doubt Asimov copied Simak when he later extended his original robot novels to make R. Daneel Olivaw effectively immortal and mind-reading.  (If he did, he didn't take much from the Simak story. His R. Daneel was already named, his personality is nothing like Richard Daniel's,and his psionic powers are completely different. (Richard Daniel can manipulate the world in wondrous ways, but is not shown as being able to read or manipulate minds.))